# Would software RAID 1 be broken if I move both drives to a new PC?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, software-raid

Does a RAID 1 setup by software (win) break once you move both drives to another Win PC? Is there any way to bind the drives together so that the RAID setup stays, even after changing motherboard/cpu?

Answer (score 0):

If this is pure Windows software-raid this has been answered before: see the answer linked to by Techie007 in the comment.

If it is pure hardware raid with a real raid-controller as a PCI/PCIe card you can move the raid-controller together with the disks.

If it is a hybrid form (also known as fake-raid) consisting of software in Windows in combination with a limited bios based raid or a motherboard raid-chip then you are out of luck.
In that case the system is in 999 of a 1000 cases not transferable to another mother-board. Sometimes to a motherboard with the same chip-set and same bios version, but even that is not certain. 
Even a Windows re-install or a return to a precious restore-state might kill the raid.
To be honest: The person who invented this "fake-raid" should be hanged from the highest tree. In my experience it is just to dangerous to be let loose on an innocent user.

Comment: I actually posted an answer regarding Hardware and Firmware RAIDs as well, then deleted it after I reread the question: "RAID 1 setup by software (win)", so the OP was pretty specific. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I figured I might as well be complete in my answer. Certainly regarding the risk of fake-raid. Can't warn people enough about that.

Comment: True enough. :)